# Xamarin MvvmCross iOS Bool to Color ValueConverter not changing Label Text Color

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to change an iOS Label's text color using a value converter with MvvmCross. Here's a little bit of the code(this is in the Core project):

```
public class BoolToColorValueConverter 
        : MvxValueConverter<bool, object>
    {
        protected override object Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MvxColor mvxColor = null;
            if(value)
                mvxColor = new MvxColor(255, 0, 0);
            else 
                mvxColor = new MvxColor(0, 0, 0);

            var nativeColorConv = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNativeColor>();

            return nativeColorConv.ToNative(mvxColor);
        }
    }
```

And then, on my binding:

```
this.CreateBinding(LabelName).For(s => s.TextColor).To((MyViewModel vm) => vm.BooleanPropertyThatChangesAtSomePoint).WithConversion("BoolToColor").Apply();
```

But for some reason when the boolean property changes from true to false, I see other fields bound to that property changing properly, but not the label's text color.

I've seen @slodge videos, tutorials, downloaded git examples but still cannot get this to work. I think that it has to do with the converter not returning the proper value since I put break points and the converter is been triggered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if that piece of code is the only reference to `TextColor` in your app, then the assembly linking process is likely optimising away some of `UILabel`'s properties when `LinkerBehaviour` is set to `Link SDK assemblies only` or `Link all assemblies`. If that is the case for your project, the fix to is either to change `LinkerBehaviour` to `Don't link` (not ideal), or to add the following method to [LinkerPleaseInclude](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/11/11/dealing-with-the-linker-in-xamarin-apps/):

```
public void Include()
{
    var label = new UILabel
    {
        TextColor = UIColor.Black
    };
}
```

If that isn't the only issue, then you haven't installed the [Mvx Color Plugin](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/color). Doing so will should solve your issue. If it doesn't, consider redoing your binding as follows:

```
var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<MyViewController, MyViewModel >();

bindingSet.Bind(LabelName).For(c => c.TextColor).To(vm => vm.TestBoolean).WithConversion(new BoolToColorValueConverter());

bindingSet.Apply();
```

P.S. - Just a tip:

The color plugin gives you access to `MvxColorValueConverter`, which provides you with a more succinct way to do your color conversion:

```
public class BoolToColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert(object value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value
            ? new MvxColor(255, 0, 0)
            : new MvxColor(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke and thanks for the edits. I do have MvxColors plug installed. I don't quite get the LinkerPleaseInclude approach. I cannot find that class on my project so I assume it has to be added manually. I followed your approach using the MvxColorValueConverter but i get an error when the app starts. I will follow through your suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Actually using the MvxColor approach did the trick. I was missing the Mvx Color Plugin on the IOS project. I had it in the Core project but not in the IOS one. Thanks a lot Luke.

Comment: General rule of thumb when using Mvx plugins is to make sure you add the plugin to both the Core and Platform projects. Plugins typically have a portable interface and platform specific implementations, so adding both ensures that it works properly.